# deactivate borders within the grid and just leave a box

Tags: html, css

I'm no good in css, I just want to remove only the edges inside the box, and leave only the outer edges.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements</h1>
<p>A Grid Layout must have a parent element with the <em>display</em> property set to <em>grid</em> or <em>inline-grid</em>.</p>
<p>Direct child element(s) of the grid container automatically becomes grid items.</p>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid

Comment: Did you try removing your `border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);` rule?

Comment: yes, but deletes all the borders, 
as I said, I want to have the outer edges, the ones that form a box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way you can accomplish that by removing the border on the grid items and using the outline property on the container:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  outline-offset: -10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements</h1>
<p>A Grid Layout must have a parent element with the <em>display</em> property set to <em>grid</em> or <em>inline-grid</em>.</p>
<p>Direct child element(s) of the grid container automatically becomes grid items.</p>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

To do this you only have to create a container box with border.

```css
.grid-container {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements</h1>
<p>A Grid Layout must have a parent element with the <em>display</em> property set to <em>grid</em> or <em>inline-grid</em>.</p>
<p>Direct child element(s) of the grid container automatically becomes grid items.</p>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">6</div>
    <div class="grid-item">7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">8</div>
    <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also change your Code like this:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #2196F3;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements</h1>
<p>A Grid Layout must have a parent element with the <em>display</em> property set to <em>grid</em> or <em>inline-grid</em>.</p>
<p>Direct child element(s) of the grid container automatically becomes grid items.</p>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```